# Inserted row id is greater than all the entry in table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-database

I have a method like this:

```
private void insertData() {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(name, "aName");
    cv.put(lastName , "aLastName");

    Uri returnedUri = getContentResolver().insert(CONTENT_URI, cv);
    Log.e("number of row : " , returnedUri.toString());

}
```

I have 4 rows in my database and in the log message it will return .../persons/31 or a greater number each time. I expect that new inserted person should have id 5. I think every time I add a new person id increase by one but after deleting a person id won't automatically decrease by one.

Comment: No when you delete it doesn't decrease by one. The autoincrement counter is not reversible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id will never decrease after delete the person because id is the unique key for every person it means if you delete one person it can not give that person identity which is id in this case to another person.Got it?

Comment: thanks for your answer . yes i got it . but what should i do now ? i want the returned id be 5 not 31 or some bigger number . what can i do for it ?

Comment: can i know your the requirement for which purpose you want this...if you know your answer than please tick my answer and upvote my answer

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty typical of SQL databases, while I don't know exactly why, or how, but they have an incremental on add counter, which means every new insertion will be +1 whatever the last value of the counter is. As best i know there's no way around this short of resetting the database